# Python numpy Error

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

My code needs to collect some information on the Internet and that the work I have done well. Now i need to take that data from database and import in numpy array.
But somewhere I have a mistake..

I'm pretty new at this all and still there are so many things I do not fully understand. Any kind of help is appreciated.

This is error:

> ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (1818,2) into
>   shape (1818)

And this is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import sqlite3 as db
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.rezultati.com/utakmica/nZudUKkp/#detalji")

#Collecting data
try:
    d_kvz = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="default-odds"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/span').text
    try:
        d_kv = float(d_kvz)
    except ValueError:
        d_kv = 1.00
except NoSuchElementException:
    d_kvz = 1.00
    d_kv = 1.00

print(d_kv)

# open new link 
driver.find_element_by_id('a-match-odds-comparison').click()
newtab = driver.current_window_handle
driver.switch_to.window(newtab)
time.sleep(2)

# open new link and collect more data
driver.find_element_by_id("bookmark-under-over").click()

try:
    granicax = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
            "//*[@id='block-under-over-ft-include-ot']/table/tbody/tr/td[preceding-sibling::td[1]/div/a[@title='bet365'] and following-sibling::td/span[@class=' odds-wrap ']]")
    granicaz = granicax[0].text

except IndexError:
    granicaz = 0

granica = float(granicaz)

print(granica)

# Collecting data from db1     
conn = db.connect('rezultati.db')
print("Connected with db1!")
conn.row_factory = lambda cursor, row: row[0]
c = conn.cursor()

br_po = c.execute("SELECT BR_PO FROM model").fetchall()
granica = c.execute("SELECT GRANICA FROM model").fetchall()
kvota = c.execute("SELECT D_KV FROM model").fetchall()

x = np.vstack((granica,kvota)).T              
y = np.vstack((br_po))

print(x)
print(y)

c.close()
conn.close()
print("Connection closed")


knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=1)
knn.fit(x,y)

knn2 = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5)
knn2.fit(x,y)

b = (knn.predict([x,y]))[0]
u = (knn2.predict([x,y]))[0]

t = b.tolist()
r = u.tolist()

print(t)
print(r)

rezultat = 0

conn2 = db.connect('ProbaStatistike.db')
print("Connected with db2")
c2 = conn2.cursor() 
c2.execute("INSERT INTO Probica VALUES (?,?,?,?)",
              (granica,t,r,rezultat,))

conn2.commit()
driver.close()    
c2.close()
conn2.close()
print("Connection closed")
```

Comment: Can you add the full stack trace so we can see where the error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

The error is trying to tell you that two arrays are being used together where they should be the same size but they are different (e.g. `x+y` where x and y are numpy arrays of different sizes will give an error).

It's hard to say for sure where this is happening without further information but at a guess, this looks wrong:

```
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=1)
knn.fit(x,y)

knn2 = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5)
knn2.fit(x,y)

b = (knn.predict([x,y]))[0]
u = (knn2.predict([x,y]))[0]
```

Specifically, having done `fit` using `(x,y)`, its unlikely that you mean to do `predict` using both `x` and `y` also, you'd normally call predict with just `x` (or better, a test set that is distinct from but statistically related to the original x).

See the Iris example here for more information:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/statistical_inference/supervised_learning.html